# Преобразование ссылки на изображение в sprite. Unity 2d

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли как-то в Unity преобразовать ссылку на изображение в sprite, чтобы потом передать его в элемент UI Image? Например, имеется ссылка https://i.stack.imgur.com/60rA3.jpg
Её нужно преобразовать в sprite. Если так можно, то напишите, пожалуйста, реализацию.

Answer (score 0):

Если умеешь читать пиксели `jpg`, можно создать `Texture2D`. [Texture2D.SetPixel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixel.html)

А уже из текстуры создать спрайт. [Sprite.Create](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Sprite.Create.html)

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение сам:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ImageParse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image im;
    private const float HEIGHT = 292.1003f;
    public string url;
    private RectTransform rectTransform;

    public IEnumerator Parse()
    {
        rectTransform = im.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        using (WWW www = new WWW(url))
        {
            yield return www;
            Renderer renderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderer.material.mainTexture = www.texture;
            im.material = renderer.material;
            rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2((www.texture.width * HEIGHT) / www.texture.height, HEIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

HEIGHT - высота объекта типа Image, под которую подгоняются размеры